# How do I prevent reload when a user is going to write something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My website has a simple messaging system where users write messages and the recipients answer back, which is defined as chatting.

I'm using an HTML to keep the page refreshing until the person receives a new message.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;URL=chat_5999468.php"/>
```

It keeps refreshing the page in every 15 seconds, so if a new message intrudes, it pops up. **BUT** it reloads the page even whilst the recipient is typing.

How do I prevent this reload when a user is typing his message in jQuery?

**Edit**: Page HTML (Similar to this):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <head> <title>Untitled</title> <meta charset="UTF-8"/> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;URL=chat_5999468.php"/> <style> #b { color: #000; } .chat-input input[type="text"] { width: 65%; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #999999; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 15px; padding: 10px; color: #0084ff; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; } input:focus,button:focus,input,button { outline: none!important; } .chat-input input[type="submit"] { color: #000; background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAjD2.jpg) no-repeat; height: 47px; width: 47px; border: none; } .chat77 ul{ list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; } .chat77 ul li{ display:inline-block; clear: both; padding: 8px; border-radius: 30px; margin-bottom: 2px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; } .message-2 { background: #eee; float: left; } .message-me { float: right; background: #0084ff; color: #fff; } .message-2 + .message-me{ border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; } .message-2 + .message-me{ border-top-right-radius: 5px; border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; } .message-me:last-of-type { border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; } </style> </head> <body> <div class="chat-input"><label><form method="post" action="chat_5999468.php" ><input type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Write here..." /><input type="submit" name="submit_msg" value="" /></form></label></div><center><div id="chat-status">Online Mark Zuckerberg | <a href="chat_5999468.php">Refresh</a></div></center><br /><div class="chat77"><ul><script>var book="Me: 3";if(book=="Me: 3" ){document.write("<li class='message-me'>3</li>");}else{document.write("<li class='message-2'><a href='/profile_12.php?u=Mark+Zuckerberg' id='b' target='_top'>3</a></li>");}</script><script>var book="Mark Zuckerberg: 2";if(book=="Me: 2" ){document.write("<li class='message-me'>2</li>");}else{document.write("<li class='message-2'><a href='/profile_12.php?u=Mark+Zuckerberg' id='b' target='_top'>2</a></li>");}</script><script>var book="Me: Message1";if(book=="Me: Message1" ){document.write("<li class='message-me'>Message1</li>");}else{document.write("<li class='message-2'><a href='/profile_12.php?u=Mark+Zuckerberg' id='b' target='_top'>Message1</a></li>");}</script></ul></div><br /> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Pausing the refreshing is just going to cause more issues. A much better plan would be to not use the refresh/polling pattern at all. Research Websockets or Server Side Events instead.

Comment: But I'm currently using it. Changing the whole system isn't a good idea for me right now!

Comment: If your users are complaining already then what you're trying to do isn't going to make it any better to use

Comment: @Rory To make it better, I've asked this question!

Comment: What about `jQuery.ajax()` with `get` in a loop function?

Comment: @Patrick Can you please answer this question with your code?

Comment: @user8536056 That was just a thought, I have unfortunately no code.

Comment: Completely agreed with the first comment (review your whole design), hence I won't post it as an answer, but to stop a meta refresh, use `window.stop()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can think is `jQuery.ajax()`. See here for the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

#### This answer is for you if you want a alternative for your `meta` tag.

You could get the content of the updated site, search for a specific `div` or something like that and check if there's a new entry.

---

**This is just an example** how you **could** do it!

First of all, create a loop function:

```
setInterval(function(){
}, 15000); // The loop function will check every 15 seconds
```

After that, create the `ajax()` call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR URL HERE',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        var check = $(data).find('#chat');
        // Here you get the `div` -> `#chat`
        // Now you could check if there is something new
    }
});
```

I dont know how your chat is coded, but I think there's something with timestamps. Just check if there's a `div`(?) with a newer timestamp than your opened site:

```
var compareMe = $('#chat').find('.entry span').last().attr('class');
var compareOther = $(data).find('.entry span').last().attr('class');
```

In my case there's a `div` with `id="chat"` and this have `div`'s which have a `class="entry` which got a `span` with a `class="1504155239"` (thats the timestamp for the message).

Here's an example:

```js
var compareMe = $('#chat').find('.entry span').last().attr('class');
console.log(compareMe);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat">
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="1504155239">1504155239: </span>
    Hello There! First!
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="1504155254">1504155254: </span>
    Hey! Ah, I'm second?
  </div>
</div>
```

So the only thing that you have to do now is to check if `compareMe` and `compareOther` is the same or newer.

```
// Lets cast them first to int because of reasons.
// Just kidding, it's safer to cast them and then check if they are newer
compareMe = parseInt(compareMe);
compareOther = parseInt(compareOther);
if (compareMe != compareOther && compareMe > compareOther) {
    // Now you can reload.
}
```

---

---

At the end it would look like this:

**THIS SNIPPET DON'T WORK!** It's just here to visualize how it can be done!

```js
setInterval(function(){ // This is the loop function
  $.ajax({
    url: '<YOUR URL HERE>',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      var check = $(data).find('#chat');
      // Here you get the `div` -> `#chat`

      var compareMe = $('#chat').find('.entry span').last().attr('class');
      var compareOther = $(check).find('.entry span').last().attr('class');

      // Now you could check if there is something new

      // Lets cast them first to int because of reasons.
      // Just kidding, it's safer to cast them and then check if they are newer
      compareMe = parseInt(compareMe);
      compareOther = parseInt(compareOther);
      if (compareMe != compareOther && compareMe > compareOther) {
          // Now you can reload.
      }
    }
  });
}, 15000); // The loop function will check every 15 seconds
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chat">
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="1504155239">1504155239: </span>
    Hello There! First!
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <span class="1504155254">1504155254: </span>
    Hey! Ah, I'm second?
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

Since you've copied your `HTML` in here, I can help you more specifically.
This is an example for your code.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      var check = $(data).find('.chat77');
      var compareMe = $('.chat77').find('li').last().text();
      var compareOther = $(check).find('li').last().text();
      if (compareMe != compareOther && $('.chat-input').find('input').first().val() == "") {
        location.reload();
      }
    }
  });
}, 3000);
```

I would prefer that you add a timestamp to the messages and check this instead of `string`s.

Comment: Especially my site is optimized for feature phones! However I'm not able to continue with the timestamp. Definitely, users can see the time when (s)he is received the message, but in this form:- example:- 31 August, 2017 01:03PM. Unfortunately I don't have any timestamp feature like that!

Comment: Just use a different selector?

Comment: Can you please explain it with an other selector?

Comment: In my code, where I check `find('.entry span').last().attr('class');`. Just change this to your wanted `id/class` or `div/span/element/...`. Poorly, I don't know how your "chat"-[DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) looks like.

Comment: I've included DOM! Code may need to be filtered. It is quite hard to read!

Comment: @user8536056 I've updated it. Look at the end of the Answer.

Comment: My overall javascript is looking like this(same):- `setInterval(function(){ $.ajax({ url: '/', type: 'GET', success: function(data) { var check = $(data).find('.chat77'); var compareMe = $('.chat77').find('li').last().text(); var compareOther = $(check).find('li').last().text(); compareMe = parseInt(compareMe); compareOther = parseInt(compareOther); if (compareMe != compareOther){ } } }); }, 3000); ` but amazing, nothing happened!  And I appreciate you as you helped me till the last point.

Comment: @user8536056 You don't have a reload in your code. Thats why nothing happens. Just add between this: `if (compareMe != compareOther) { /* HERE */ }` this: `location.reload();` and delete the two lines with `parseInt(..)`. I've edited the answer again.

Comment: Oh! I was running for that js code, which works same as this code:- `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=chat_5999468.php"/>`! What a foolish I am! 

Comment: @user8536056 Uhm, what do you mean? It should do the same like this `meta` tag but which only reload if you got a new message?

Comment: You may haven't read my question carefully! I wrote a question about pausing the refresh while using `HTML` `Input` & you posted an answer that constantly refreshes the page in every 3 seconds. If I change the number into 15000, it will work same as the `meta` code, mentioned above.

Comment: @user8536056 And that's exactly what I'm into. It's the same, but better and you'll dont need a pause. That's why there's this: _This is just an example how you could do it_. I think you'll need to rethink your design.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153426/discussion-between-patrick-mlr-and-user8536056).